Regex to find the exact money in NodeJs from Statement
Here I have my money statements as MUR 30,000 or MUR 30000 or 30000 MUR or 30,000 MUR.
I have got already a regex which works for MUR 30000 and MUR 30,000.
/MUR \d+(,\d+)?/g

But now I need a regex that works for all four variants.

Try this /(?<currency1>MUR)?\s?(?<amount>\d+)\s?(?<currency2>MUR)?/
but it will have the numbers on different index depending if they are at front or at back

Many answers already, one more option: \b(?:MUR |(?=\d\S* MUR))\d[\d,]*(?: MUR)? or if you just need the number, capture like this.

You can use the following regex pattern:
/(?:MUR\s)?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\sMUR)?/g

(?:MUR\s)?: Match

es "MUR " if it appears at the beginning. The (?: ... ) is a
non-capturing group, and the ? makes it optional
\d{1,3}: Matches 1
to 3 digits (?:,\d{3})*: Matches groups of three digits preceded by a
comma, zero or more times
(?:\sMUR)?: Matches " MUR" if it appears
at the end


If I understood your request right, here is a regex to find all the variations:
\b(?:MUR\s?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|MUR\s?\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\s?MUR|\d+\s?MUR)\b

I used /gmx flags
UPD:
1st Alternative:
MUR\s?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*

MUR matches the characters "MUR" literally (case sensitive)
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) 
? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9]) 
{1,3} matches the previous token between 1 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Non-capturing group (?:,\d{3})* 
* matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 
, matches the character , (comma) literally (case sensitive)

2nd Alternative:
MUR\s?\d+

MUR matches the characters "MUR" literally (case sensitive)
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) 
? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9]) 
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

3rd Alternative:
\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\s?MUR

\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9]) 
{1,3} matches the previous token between 1 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Non-capturing group (?:,\d{3})* 
* matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 
, matches the character "," (comma) literally (case sensitive) 
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9]) 
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) 
? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 
MUR matches the characters "MUR" literally (case sensitive)


4th Alternative: \d+\s?MUR

\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9]) 
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) 
? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
MUR matches the characters "MUR" literally (case sensitive)

\b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
Global pattern flags:

m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You could match the digits part once, and then check if there is either MUR before or after it using lookaround assertions.
Note that you can surround the pattern with word boundaries \b to prevent partial word matches.
\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:(?<=MUR [\d,]+)|(?= MUR))

Regex demo


const regex = /\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:(?<=MUR [\d,]+)|(?= MUR))/g;
const s = `Here I have statements here my money in statement as MUR 30,000 or MUR 30000 or 30000 MUR or 30,000 MUR 3,0`;
console.log(s.match(regex));



Or use 2 alternations
 (?<=MUR )\d+(?:,\d+)?|\d+(?:,\d+)?(?= MUR)

Regex demo


const regex = /(?<=MUR )\d+(?:,\d+)?|\d+(?:,\d+)?(?= MUR)/g;
const s = `Here I have statements here my money in statement as MUR 30,000 or MUR 30000 or 30000 MUR or 30,000 MUR 3,0`;
console.log(s.match(regex));




Try this
/(?P<currency1>MUR)?\s?(?P<amount>\d+,?\d+)\s?(?P<currency2>MUR)?/

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you want to get only digits followed_by or after 'MUR' 
then use regex:
      /((?<=MUR\s?)\d+(,\d+)?|\d+(,\d+)?(?=\s?MUR))/g
or
      /((?<=MUR)\s?)\d+(,\d+)?|\d+(,\d+)?\s?(?=MUR))/g   -- need to trim

Output:  
Test Regex: Regex101

If you want to get digits followed_by or after 'MUR' 
then use regex:
      /((?:MUR\s?)\d+(,\d+)?|\d+(,\d+)?(?:\s?MUR))/g

Output: 
Test Regex: Regex101
